# Combine rows with unique ID with the use of arrays, where all data is being merged and separated by ",'

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have a large data set where column A has the unique ID and then several other columns.

I would like to combine the unique ID to 1 row with also keeping all the data of the other columns combined and separated by a ","
See attached picture.

I already tried below VBA for it, but it only results that the first 2 columns (A and B) are combined.

Is there a way to amend this so it works on more than 2 columns?

[image: Example Excel]

```
Sub CombineData()

' Source
Const sName As String = "Test"
Const sDelimiter As String = ", "
' Destination
Const dName As String = "Test2"
Const dFirstCellAddress As String = "A2"
Const dDelimiter As String = ", "

' Source range to an array.

Dim Data As Variant
Dim rCount As Long

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sName).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    rCount = .Rows.Count - 1
    If rCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data or only headers
    Data = .Resize(rCount, 2).Offset(1).Value
End With

' Array to a dictionary of dictionaries.

Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

Dim Key As Variant
Dim Item As Variant
Dim r As Long
Dim n As Long

For r = 1 To rCount
    Item = CStr(Data(r, 2))
    If Not IsError(Item) Then
        If Len(Item) > 0 Then
            Key = Data(r, 1)
            If Not IsError(Key) Then
                If Len(Key) > 0 Then
                    Item = Split(Item, sDelimiter)
                    If Not dict.Exists(Key) Then
                        Set dict(Key) = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                    End If
                    For n = 0 To UBound(Item)
                        dict(Key)(Item(n)) = Empty
                    Next n
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
Next r

rCount = dict.Count
If rCount = 0 Then Exit Sub ' only error values or blanks

' Dictionary of dictionaries to the array.

ReDim Data(1 To rCount, 1 To 2)
r = 0

For Each Key In dict.keys
    r = r + 1
    Data(r, 1) = Key
    Data(r, 2) = Join(dict(Key).keys, dDelimiter)
   

Next Key

' Array to the destination range.

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirstCellAddress).Resize(, 2)
    .Resize(rCount).Value = Data
    .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row - rCount + 1).Offset(rCount).Clear
End With

MsgBox "Data combined.", vbInformation
```

End Sub

Comment: You complicated a little too much your code. I would like to understand why do you need  "Apple, Apple" in the first column and not only "Apple". The rest should be obvious, I think... If you clarify this aspect I can post a piece of working code. And why need of a "Match ID"? The dictionary have to process all the same fruits even if the range are not sorted.

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next updated code. It uses only a unique dictionary which keeps  fruits name as (unique) keys and the concatenated existing data in an array. It returns without 'Match ID`, which is useless, since the dictionary key/unique fruit is enough:

```
Sub CombineData()
 Const sName As String = "Test", sDelimiter As String = ", "
 Const dName As String = "Test2", dFirstCellAddress As String = "A2"

 ' Source range to an array.
 Dim Data, rCount As Long, arrHead

 With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(sName).Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    rCount = .rows.count - 1
    If rCount < 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data or only headers
    Data = .Resize(rCount).Offset(1).Value2
    arrHead = .rows(1).Offset(, 1).Value2 'place the relevant header in an array
 End With

 ' Array to a dictionary:
 Dim dict As Object: Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 dict.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

 Dim r As Long, arrIt, arrFin, i As Long

 For r = 1 To rCount
        If Not dict.Exists(Data(r, 2)) Then
                dict.Add Data(r, 2), Array(Data(r, 3), Data(r, 4), Data(r, 5))
        Else
                arrIt = dict(Data(r, 2)) 'an array item cannot be updated directly
                For i = 0 To UBound(arrIt)
                    arrIt(i) = arrIt(i) & sDelimiter & Data(r, i + 2)
                Next i
                dict(Data(r, 2)) = arrIt
        End If
 Next r

 If dict.count = 0 Then Exit Sub 

 ReDim arrFin(1 To dict.count, 1 To 4)

 ' Dictionary to final array.
 Dim Key As Variant
 r = 0
 For Each Key In dict.Keys
    r = r + 1
    arrFin(r, 1) = Key: arrIt = dict(Key)
    For i = 0 To UBound(arrIt)
        arrFin(r, i + 2) = arrIt(i)
    Next i
 Next Key

 ' drop the process array content at once:
 With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(dName).Range(dFirstCellAddress).Resize(UBound(arrFin), 4)
    .Value = arrFin
    .cells(1).Offset(-1).Resize(1, UBound(arrHead, 2)).Value2 = arrHead
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
 End With

MsgBox "Data combined.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: @DFW Didn't you find some time to test the above code answer? If tested, didn't it return as you need?

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, Thanks for above :-)

Comment: I had to work this week so I'll test this weekend you're code and let you know ok?

Comment: @DFW Please, send some feedback after testing it. If it will happen this year should be OK... :)

Comment: Good morning FaneDuru, it worked..thanks :-) I tested it and it works now as expected so I can work further on this to complete this project.  Again thanks for your help into this.

Comment: @DFW Glad i could help! But I would like to remind you that we here, when somebody answer our question in a convenient way, we tick the code left side check box, in order to make it **accepted answer**. In this way, somebody else searching for a similar issue will know that the provided solution works...